# How to fill column in dataframe with repeating value a certain number of times?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have many .xtl files. I'm trying to write a loop. I need to place part of information from its file name into df and save it by overwriting but I can't find solution how to fill columns.

```
    df = pd.read_html('my_file - 35 F - 2018.xls') 
    df = df[0] 
    df["A"] = "" 
    df["B"] = ""
    rows = df.shape[0] 
    a = file_name[10:13]  
    b = file_name[14:16] 
    print(rows, a, b)
```

And as an output we can get:

```
rows = 55, 
a = 35,
b = F.
```

I want to add "a" and "b" into DataFrame in "A" and "B" columns "rows" = 55 times.
Im sorry for very messy question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it simply by:

```
  df = pd.read_html('my_file - 35 F - 2018.xls') 
    df = df[0] 
    rows = df.shape[0] 
    a = file_name[10:13]  
    b = file_name[14:16]
    df["A"] = [a] * rows 
    df["B"] = [b] * rows
```